# Is instant preview not yet supported to use ar core with depth api in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm using Unity 2019.4.10f1 and have just updated the AR Core unity package to version 1.20 since [there was a bug using instant preview with the last version 1.19](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/759).

Anyhow, instant preview now works on my app, however the Depth API never initializes (meaning `DepthSource.Initialized` never changes to `true`). I also tried the the Hello AR scene and the option to turn on depth api is greyed out there.

I think I read about instant preview not supporting depth api yet in the [limitations section](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/instant-preview) of the
instant preview guide, however I can't find any reference to it now, so I was wondering if this was still the case, or if I'm missing something else.